# Pass a dynamic value to a function in angular with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to use a link to dynamically translate a website.

This is my HTML:

```
<a  ng-click="switchLanguage('{{language.value}}')" >Translate</a>
```

{{language.value}} is a dynamic value taken from a json file and I can verify that upon runtime, it does get populated with the proper value ('en-us','ja-jp', etc...)

And here's my function inside a controller:

```
function switchLanguage(newlan) {
    console.log(newlan);
}
```

However, everytime I click on the link, the console shows the value as {{language.value}}, instead of the proper value (ex: en-us).

How do I make  the value inside the ng-click pass the correct parameter to the function?

Comment: try this <a  ng-click="switchLanguage(language.value)" >Translate</a>

Comment: for those interested in `angular` (not js), the syntax is `(click)="switchLanguage(lang.value)"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `ng-click="switchLanguage(language.value)"`

Here is the **PLUNKER**: http://plnkr.co/edit/uOUD9f1P3tKp3IlGsjBK?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
<a ng-click="switchLanguage('{{language.value}}')" >Translate</a>
```

Use this

```
<a ng-click="switchLanguage(language.value)" >Translate</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the value in this way :

```
<a ng-click="switchLanguage(language.value)">Translate</a>
```

This `<a ng-click="switchLanguage('{{language.value}}')" >Translate</a>`
will pass the '{{language.value}}' as a value.

Comment: how can we pass like this

<a (click)="language.value">Translate</a>

language.value is dynamic

is it possible?